# Why my images are taking too much time to load?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, windows-phone-7, delay

I've read about the [`LowProfileImageLoader`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/08/never-do-today-what-you-can-put-off-till-tomorrow-deferredloadlistbox-and-stackpanel-help-windows-phone-7-lists-scroll-smoothly-and-consistently.aspx). It will only load the image when the user can see it and will avoid blocking the UI thread.

I added it and tested on my application. All 25 images are from the exact same URL. With the default image it took a little to load but all other images were cached, and the scroll got super fast.

With the `LowProfileImageLoader` the images were not cached, it was loading 1 by 1 even though it was the exact same image. And when I scrolled down then up it would load the image all over again. And it takes a long time to load them.

Do I have to configure something to keep the images on cache? How do I configure this `LowProfileImageLoader`?

Comment: Interesting, as the `LowProfileImageLoader` is meant to use cache. I would suggest you look into the source code for the `LowProfileImageLoader` and do the necessary modifications yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood by looking at a windows phone mango video presentation, images are automatically cached without you doing anything.

Video I'm talking about: http://www.wpcentral.com/multitasking-mango-demoed-detail